# Using Python os.walk or os.path to build an XML file based on subdirectory file contents

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

Let me try to describe this as simply as possible.

**Problem:** Workspace.xml is read by an IDE in order to load files into it's directory tree. We recently started adding "Package" sub-directories such as **Baz** below and I'm having trouble building  elements for the Baz subdirectory.

Here is what the **correct output** should look like:

```
<Workspace NAME="Workspace">
  <Project NAME="Bar" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1"/>
    <File NAME="bar" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\bar.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
        <Package NAME="Baz" TYPE="PACKAGE" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
            <File NAME="baz" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\baz.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
        </Package>
  </Project>
  <Project NAME="Foo" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1"/>
    <File NAME="Foo" PATH="C:\Project\Foo\Foo.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">Foo</File>
  </Project>
</Workspace>
```

From this imagined directory structure:

```
C:\Project\Workspace.xml
|
Project\Foo\foo.txt
|
Project\Bar\bar.txt
   |
  Project\Bar\Baz\baz.txt
```

Here is the **broken code** using os.walk and os.path:

```
from lxml import etree
import os

workspace = etree.Element('Workspace', NAME = 'Workspace')
path = 'C:\Project'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    print(subdirs)
    print(files)
    for entry in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,entry)
        print(os.path.join(path,entry))
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and not entry.startswith('.') and entry != 'config':
            project = etree.SubElement(workspace,"Project")
            project.set('NAME',entry)
            project.set('TYPE','Standard')
            project.set('COPY_TO_PATH','')
            project.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
            project.set('GENOPT','1')
            for doc in files:
                #print(doc)
                docPath = fullpath
                filename = os.path.splitext(doc)[0]
                extension = os.path.splitext(doc)[1]
                if extension == '.txt':
                    file = etree.SubElement(project, "File")
                    file.set('NAME',filename)
                    file.set('PATH',docPath)
                    file.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
                    file.set('GENOPT','4096')
                    file.text = filename
                    for entry in subdirs:
                        fullpath = os.path.join(path,entry)
                        print(os.path.join(path,entry))
                        if os.path.isdir(fullpath) and not entry.startswith('.') and entry != 'config':
                            package = etree.SubElement(project,"Package")
                            package.set('NAME',entry)
                            package.set('TYPE','PACKAGE')
                            package.set('COPY_TO_PATH','')
                            package.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
                            package.set('GENOPT','1')
                            for doc in files:
                                print(doc)
                                docPath = fullpath
                                filename = os.path.splitext(doc)[0]
                                extension = os.path.splitext(doc)[1]
                                if extension == '.txt':
                                    file = etree.SubElement(package, "File")
                                    file.set('NAME',filename)
                                    file.set('PATH',docPath)
                                    file.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
                                    file.set('GENOPT','4096')
                                    file.text = filename
                                    for entry in path:
                                        fullpath = os.path.join(path,entry)
                                        if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and not entry.startswith('.') and entry != 'config':
                                            package = etree.SubElement(project,"Package")
                                            package.set('NAME',entry)
                                            package.set('TYPE','PACKAGE')
                                            package.set('COPY_TO_PATH','')
                                            package.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
                                            package.set('GENOPT','1')
                                            for doc in files:
                                                print(doc)
                                                docPath = fullpath
                                                filename = os.path.splitext(doc)[0]
                                                extension = os.path.splitext(doc)[1]
                                                if extension == '.txt':
                                                    file = etree.SubElement(package, "File")
                                                    file.set('NAME',filename)
                                                    file.set('PATH',docPath)
                                                    file.set('TRUE_JAVA','0')
                                                    file.set('GENOPT','4096')
                                                    file.text = filename


defaultWorkspaces = open("C:\Project\Workspace.xml","w")
defaultWorkspaces.write(etree.tostring(workspace, pretty_print=True, encoding = "unicode"))
```

**Broken Output** Package should be C:\Project\Bar\Baz\Baz.txt NOT C:\Project\Bar\Baz:

```
<Workspace NAME="Workspace">
  <Project NAME="Workspace.xml" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1"/>
  <Project NAME="bar.txt" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
    <File NAME="bar" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\bar.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
    <Package NAME="Baz" TYPE="PACKAGE" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
      <File NAME="bar" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\Baz" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
    </Package>
  </Project>
  <Project NAME="Baz.txt" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
    <File NAME="Baz" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\Baz\Baz.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">Baz</File>
  </Project>
  <Project NAME="Foo.txt" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
    <File NAME="Foo" PATH="C:\Project\Foo\Foo.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">Foo</File>
  </Project>
</Workspace>
```

I have tried various control structure modifications and list filters without a working solutions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to given file tree, shouldn't the desired `<File>` node under the package `Baz` contain the attribute value of the file-path __with  sub-folder__ `"C:\Project\Bar\Baz\baz.txt"` instead `PATH="C:\Project\Bar\baz.txt"` ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The first if-statement inside loop `for doc in files:`, namely `if extension == '.txt':`, evaluates to `True` for a text-file. Not only inside a project folder, but **also inside a *package* folder** like `Baz`.

Thus `Baz\baz.txt` is added as subelement `<File>` inside parent element `<Project>`.

This leads to unwanted XML with additional project node having a nested file:

```xml
  <Project NAME="Baz.txt" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
    <File NAME="Baz" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\Baz\Baz.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">Baz</File>
  </Project>
```

#### Solution

Instead the if-statement should divert differently depending on the parent.
If it is a text-file as direct children of a project-folder, then just add it inside the project element.
Otherwise if it is a text-file as **children of a package-folder**, then add it inside the package element.

So you can get the nested structure like wanted:

```xml
  <Project NAME="Bar" TYPE="Standard" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1"/> <!-- premature closing of project -->
    <File NAME="bar" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\bar.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
    <Package NAME="Baz" TYPE="PACKAGE" COPY_TO_PATH="" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="1">
      <File NAME="baz" PATH="C:\Project\Bar\baz.txt" TRUE_JAVA="0" GENOPT="4096">bar</File>
    </Package>
  </Project>
```

Another spot of mal-formed XML: In the first line that the node is closing prematurely `<Project .. />` (I added a comment).